# flatness problem: every exact seq of modules remain exact upon tensor product by X

Tags: modules, flatness

I have to prove the following statements are equivalent

1. If $f:A \to B$ is a monomorphism of $R-$modules, so is $i\otimes f$
2. Every exact sequence of R-modules remains exact upon the tensor product by X

I don’t know how to prove $2\to 1 \cdots$

Comment: Hint: if $f: A \rightarrow B$ is a monomorphism, then $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow B/f(A) \rightarrow 0$ is a short exact sequence.

Comment: `\to` creates a function arrow.

Comment: Randall/// Thanks :)